# Transpose paste copied range from Excel to PowerPoint Charts

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to update a few of my slides using data from excel and pasting it to the PowerPoint Chart backend using the below code.

```
Sub updateSlides()
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Dim xlApp, xlWorkBook, xlSheet As Object

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  ' Not transposing
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = Flase
  xlApp.Visible = True

  Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("ExcelFilePath")
  Set xlSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("SheetName")

  For i = 1 To 9
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
      Set charts = .Shapes("Chart 37").Chart.ChartData
      charts.Activate
      Set chartData = charts.Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
      xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(2 + i, 2), xlSheet.Cells(2 + i, 3)).copy
      chartData.Range("B8").PasteSpecial Paste:=-4163
      ' I need to transpose the copied data here'
      charts.Workbook.Close
    End With
   If i < 9 Then
      ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Duplicate.SlideIndex
    End If
  Next i

  xlApp.Quit
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
  Set xlApp = Nothing

  ' ActivePresentation.Save

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

At line 20 I need to transpose the copied data and paste it at the destination range provided.
Any help is duly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Transpose` parameter:

```
chartData.Range("B8").PasteSpecial Paste:=-4163, Transpose:=True
```

Also correct the typo:

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False ' <--- Not Flase
```